# ¿Cómo dar estilo a un segundo checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Como puedo darle estilo al segundo checkbox y en caso de que por esas casualidades haya un tercer como haría para que reconozca los estilos

```js
var checkbox =document.querySelector('input[name=checkbox]');
  checkbox.id='micheckbox';
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.id='milabel';
  label.htmlFor='micheckbox';
  checkbox.parentNode.appendChild(label);
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%!important
}

table strong {
  color: #333333!important;
  font-family: 'Helvetica-Condensed-Black'!important;
  font-size: 22px!important;
  line-height: 22px;
}

tr:first-child td {
  margin: 16px 0 4px 0;
}

tr:last-child td {
  margin-bottom: 20px!important;
}

tr td:nth-child(even) {
  padding: 10px 15px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  float: left!important;
  clear: both!important
}

tr td:nth-child(odd) {
  padding: 0px 15px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  float: left!important;
  clear: both!important;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue57CondensedOblique'!important;
  font-size: 15px!important;
}

tr td input {
  width: 100%!important;
  height: 38px!important;
  outline: none!important;
  padding: 8px!important;
  border-left: 3px solid #a80532!important;
  border-right: initial!important;
  border-bottom: initial!important;
  border-top: initial!important;
  background-color: #f1f2f2!important;
}

tr td input[type=submit] {
  padding: 7px 15px!important;
  height: 42px!important;
  background: #a80532!important;
  border: 0 none!important;
  cursor: pointer!important;
  color: #fff!important;
  margin: 8px 0!important;
  font-family: 'Helvetica-Condensed-Black'!important;
  font-size: 17px!important;
}

tr td input[type=submit]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #a80532!important;
  color: #f1f2f2!important
}

select {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  outline: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #a80532!important;
  border-right: initial!important;
  border-bottom: initial!important;
  border-top: initial!important;
  color: #74646e;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #f1f2f2;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-position: 356px;
}

#micheckbox {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#micheckbox + label {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
#micheckbox:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
  
}
#micheckbox:checked + label:after {
  left: 33px;
}
#milabel {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: transparent;
}
#milabel:after {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  right: auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style='width:600px;background-color:white;color:black'>

  <tr>
    <td colspan='2' style='text-align:left;color:black;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;text-transform: uppercase;'><strong>¡Empezá ya mismo TÉCNICO en <br> Gestión Bancaria!</strong></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>NOMBRE
      <span style='color:red;'>*</span></td>
    <td style='width:250px;'><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='40' name='First Name' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>APELLIDO<span style='color:red;'>*</span>
    </td>
    <td style='width:250px;'><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='80' name='Last Name' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>E-MAIL<span style='color:red;'>*</span>
    </td>
    <td style='width:250px;'><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='100' name='Email' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>TEL&Eacute;FONO</td>
    <td style='width:250px;'>
      <input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='30' name='Phone' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>QUIERO SELECCIONAR LA CARRERA
    </td>
    <td style='width:250px;'>
      <input type='checkbox' style='width:250px;' maxlength='30' name='checkbox' checked="checked" />
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>QUIERO SELECCIONAR LA CARRERA
    </td>
    <td style='width:250px;'>
      <input type='checkbox' style='width:250px;' maxlength='30' name='checkbox' checked="checked" />
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center; padding-top:15px;font-size:12px;'>
      <input style='font-size:12px;color:black' type='submit' value='Enviar' />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Intenta no usar un ID si no usar clases, se supone que cuando usas ID es porque solo quieres referenciar un solo objeto, mientras que con clases, referencias a varios

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te sugerieron en un comentario, en estos casos se usan clases en lugar de ids.  Con una clase, puedes tener cuantos checkboxes como quieras.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var checkboxes =document.querySelectorAll('input[name=checkbox]');
  var cboxes = checkboxes.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < cboxes; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].classList.add('micheckbox');
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    checkboxes[i].id = 'micheckbox' + i
    label.classList.add('milabel');
    label.htmlFor='micheckbox' + i;
    checkboxes[i].parentNode.appendChild(label);
  }
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%!important
}

table strong {
  color: #333333!important;
  font-family: 'Helvetica-Condensed-Black'!important;
  font-size: 22px!important;
  line-height: 22px;
}

tr:first-child td {
  margin: 16px 0 4px 0;
}

tr:last-child td {
  margin-bottom: 20px!important;
}

tr td:nth-child(even) {
  padding: 10px 15px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  float: left!important;
  clear: both!important
}

tr td:nth-child(odd) {
  padding: 0px 15px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  float: left!important;
  clear: both!important;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue57CondensedOblique'!important;
  font-size: 15px!important;
}

tr td input {
  width: 100%!important;
  height: 38px!important;
  outline: none!important;
  padding: 8px!important;
  border-left: 3px solid #a80532!important;
  border-right: initial!important;
  border-bottom: initial!important;
  border-top: initial!important;
  background-color: #f1f2f2!important;
}

tr td input[type=submit] {
  padding: 7px 15px!important;
  height: 42px!important;
  background: #a80532!important;
  border: 0 none!important;
  cursor: pointer!important;
  color: #fff!important;
  margin: 8px 0!important;
  font-family: 'Helvetica-Condensed-Black'!important;
  font-size: 17px!important;
}

tr td input[type=submit]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #a80532!important;
  color: #f1f2f2!important
}

select {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  outline: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #a80532!important;
  border-right: initial!important;
  border-bottom: initial!important;
  border-top: initial!important;
  color: #74646e;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #f1f2f2;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-position: 356px;
}

.micheckbox {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.micheckbox + label {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.micheckbox:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
  
}
.micheckbox:checked + label:after {
  left: 33px;
}
.milabel {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: transparent;
}
.milabel:after {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  right: auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style='width:600px;background-color:white;color:black'>

  <tr>
    <td colspan='2' style='text-align:left;color:black;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;text-transform: uppercase;'><strong>¡Empezá ya mismo TÉCNICO en <br> Gestión Bancaria!</strong></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>NOMBRE
      <span style='color:red;'>*</span></td>
    <td style='width:250px;'><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='40' name='First Name' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>APELLIDO<span style='color:red;'>*</span>
    </td>
    <td style='width:250px;'><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='80' name='Last Name' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>E-MAIL<span style='color:red;'>*</span>
    </td>
    <td style='width:250px;'><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='100' name='Email' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>TEL&Eacute;FONO</td>
    <td style='width:250px;'>
      <input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='30' name='Phone' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>QUIERO SELECCIONAR LA CARRERA
    </td>
    <td style='width:250px;'>
      <input type='checkbox' style='width:250px;' maxlength='30' name='checkbox' checked="checked" />
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>QUIERO SELECCIONAR LA CARRERA
    </td>
    <td style='width:250px;'>
      <input type='checkbox' style='width:250px;' maxlength='30' name='checkbox' checked="checked" />
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center; padding-top:15px;font-size:12px;'>
      <input style='font-size:12px;color:black' type='submit' value='Enviar' />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```